# Setting a QADPermission with identity from a CSV?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to run Add-QADPermission with a pipeline input from a CSV file to provide account names, but when I run the command, the output requests a value for the account parameter.

```
Import-Csv .\createuserslistfinal.csv | Select-Object -Property "Logon Username" | Add-QADPermission "User-Change-Password" -Deny -ApplyTo ThisObjectOnly
```

Any help would be apriciated, even if it's through a different command. I need to take the "Logon Username" name property from the CSV file and set the above permission for every account that matches.

I've also tried

```
Import-Csv "createuserslistfinal.csv" | ForEach-Object {

 Add-QADPermission -identity $_."Logon Username" `
 -ExtendedRight "User-Change-Password" -Deny -ApplyTo ThisObjectOnly
}
```

Comment: Anyone? I'm still pretty stumped.

Comment: I don't use Quest CmdLets, but in  [Add-QADPermission](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Add-QADPermission) documentation you will find examples. You should read it, test the examples and at least give values to required parameters (`-account`).